# What this & symbol means in C?

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I get below code in a project which one is using JNI. By now I could understand that this is a struct array and typed as JNINativeMethod, first name is the method defined in Java code ("description", "run_"...), second one define the method type and return type, and third one is the method pointer.

But what is this '&' symbol means before the method name, e.g. "(void *)&Java_Test_description"? It is a basic question, sorry I didn't find any helpful info from the internet. I see some guide of JNI just using this way like "(void *)Java_Test_description", it doesn't use this '&' symbol.

*Code in jni.c*

```
static JNINativeMethod classTest_methods[] = {
{ "description", "()Ljava/lang/String;", (void *)&Java_Test_description },
{ "skip", "()Z", (void *)&Java_Test_skip },
{ "skip_reason", "()Ljava/lang/String;", (void *)&Java_Test_skip_reason },
{ "run_", "(I)Z", (void *)&Java_Test_run_ },                               
};
```

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in JNI. JNI is an *API.* It means something *in the language you are programming in,* which appears to be C. In this case, as you are using function addresses, it really doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: Thanks your reply, @EJP. My expression is inaccurate, what I mean is that this '&' symbol appears in the jni.c. And I'm not sure what is it doing.

Comment: They better not be function addresses, as casting between function pointers and data pointers isn't meaningful in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **&** returns the address of the entity that follows it; in this case, the JNI method description uses the address of a global function that implements the native method. A list of these descriptions is passed to **RegisterNatives()** JNI function.

In this case, the [**&** address operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/address-of-operator-amp) can be omitted, because for function

```
jboolean Java_Test_run_(int n);
```

the C compiler resolves

```
(void *)Java_Test_run_
```

same as

```
(void *)&Java_Test_run_
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Cohn. From what you said, I think I could treat them same as with or without '&' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

That symbol is the address operator. Using it before any variable will return the memory address of the latter.

It can be usefull when you want to avoid working on copies of variables that are created by functions for example.

see passing by value vs passing by reference/address: http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference-in-c.php